# Retrieval of Object Id from Microsoft AAD from Flutter App

Tags: flutter, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, nosuchmethoderror, user-identification

I'm trying to retrieve the Object id of the logged-in user from the flutter app.

I have retrieved accessToken using https://pub.dev/packages/aad_oauth.
After that, I'm trying to retrieve from Microsoft graph API with a normal HTTP get method for which.
I'm getting this error:

```
NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'id' was called on null.

Receiver: null

Tried calling: id
```

Following is the code snippet:

```
Future<InfoMe> createUser(String accessToken) async{
final String apiUrl = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me';
final response =
await http.get(apiUrl,headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer $accessToken", "Content-Type": "application/json"});
if (response.statusCode == 201) {
final String responseString = response.body;
    print('$responseString');
return infoMeFromJson(responseString);
  } else {
return null;
  }
}
void login() async {
try {
await oauth.login();
oauth.getIdToken().toString();
var accessToken = await oauth.getAccessToken(); //$accessToken
    final InfoMe info = await createUser(accessToken);
information = InfoMe(id: info.id);
    setState(() {
information = info;
    });
    showMessage("${information.displayName}" + " "+ '${information.id}');
 } catch (e) {
    showError(e);
  }
}
```

InfoMe.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';
InfoMe infoMeFromJson(String str) => InfoMe.fromJson(json.decode(str));
String infoMeToJson(InfoMe data) => json.encode(data.toJson());
class InfoMe {
  InfoMe({
    this.odataContext,
    this.businessPhones,
    this.displayName,
    this.givenName,
    this.jobTitle,
    this.mail,
    this.mobilePhone,
    this.officeLocation,
    this.preferredLanguage,
    this.surname,
    this.userPrincipalName,
    this.id,
  });
  String odataContext;
  List<String> businessPhones;
  String displayName;
  String givenName;
  String jobTitle;
  String mail;
  dynamic mobilePhone;
  dynamic officeLocation;
  dynamic preferredLanguage;
  dynamic surname;
  String userPrincipalName;
  String id;
  factory InfoMe.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => InfoMe(
    odataContext: json["@odata.context"],
    businessPhones: List<String>.from(json["businessPhones"].map((x) => x)),
    displayName: json["displayName"],
    givenName: json["givenName"],
    jobTitle: json["jobTitle"],
    mail: json["mail"],
    mobilePhone: json["mobilePhone"],
    officeLocation: json["officeLocation"],
    preferredLanguage: json["preferredLanguage"],
    surname: json["surname"],
    userPrincipalName: json["userPrincipalName"],
    id: json["id"],
  );
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "@odata.context": odataContext,
    "businessPhones": List<dynamic>.from(businessPhones.map((x) => x)),
    "displayName": displayName,
    "givenName": givenName,
    "jobTitle": jobTitle,
    "mail": mail,
    "mobilePhone": mobilePhone,
    "officeLocation": officeLocation,
    "preferredLanguage": preferredLanguage,
    "surname": surname,
    "userPrincipalName": userPrincipalName,
    "id": id,
  };
}
```

Dear developers kindly help me out to resolve this issue.

Comment: What is your response? Is its status code '201'?

Comment: Looks like the user is not created successfully. Can you check it?

Comment: Status code i'm getting as 201, but not getting the data. Users are already created by the admin. All the user grants are also given.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the user is not created successfully.

For creating a user, you should call **this endpoint** `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users` and set the **request body**:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

{
      "accountEnabled": true,
      "displayName": "Adele Vance",
      "mailNickname": "AdeleV",
      "userPrincipalName": "AdeleV@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
      "passwordProfile" : {
        "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
        "password": "xWwvJ]6NMw+bWH-d"
      }
}
```

You are using `POST` method with `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` endpoint without any request body.

See reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request).

Comment: The user is already been created. i have to retrieve object id of the logged in user.

Comment: @SurekhaSharadMuzumdar Getting the user should returns 200 rather than 201. 201 is creating the user. If you are trying to get the user, you should call GET method. `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`. And you should modify the condition as `if (response.statusCode == 200)`. Besides, make sure you are using auth code flow to get the access token. If the access token is acquired with client credential flow, you should use `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{UPN}` instead of `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`.

Comment: @SurekhaSharadMuzumdar I'm not familiar with Flutter. But I guess you should use `await http.get(apiUrl,headers` rather than `await http.post(apiUrl,headers` in order to call GET method.

Comment: I changed that to get method as well even after that still the output is blank.

Comment: @SurekhaSharadMuzumdar Edit your post to update the current code you are using.